# HTTP Error 500 when trying access Admin System Configuration

Tags: magento-1.9, error, system-config

In the system log I get the following error:

```
2018-04-09T14:03:13+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: 
include(Mage/Mailchimp/Helper/Data.php): failed to open stream: No such 
file or directory  in 
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/www/nilil/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2018-04-09T14:03:13+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 
'Mage/Mailchimp/Helper/Data.php' for inclusion
```

> (include_path='/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/www/nilil/app/code/local:/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/www/nilil/app/code/community:/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/www/nilil/app/code/core:/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/www/nilil/lib:.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.32/lib/php')  in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/www/nilil/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94

Comment: Are you able to flush cache, without using the Admin?

Comment: yes, I flush the cache using the terminal.

Comment: did you check if Mage/Mailchimp/Helper/Data.php file is there ?

Comment: Strangely, I did a new pull from the master repo and now it works.